# how to send imageview from one activity to other

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview

I have an imageview in listview in first activity,
I want to send my imageview into second activity on clicl of listview item.

I have tried following code-

Convert drawable image into bytearray:-

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Sending through Intent-

```
Intent intent=new Intent(PicturesList.this,PictureDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("Bitmap", byteArray);
                startActivity(intent);
```

In second activity-

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        byteArray = extras.getByteArray("Bitmap");
```

and

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                        imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

But Problem is here-

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

This require drawable image and i have imageview,
Can I convert my imageview into drawable? or anything alse?
How to send imageview instead of drawable.
Anybody have done this before.

This is how I set image in imageview

```
new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


                try {
                    URL newurl = new URL("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png");
                    bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
                    //bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50,50, true);
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            //  bitmap=imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2199/2218403922_062bc3bcf2.jpg", imageview);
                //bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, imageview.getWidth(), imageview.getHeight(), true);
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }.execute();
```

Comment: How do you set the Image to ImageView in the first place?it depends a whole lot on that actually.

Comment: I have  set image on imageview using URL.  onclick of it i want display it in second activity.

Comment: yeah that's fine. But my question in what form are you storing the image from url. You should have used drawable right?

Comment: why don't you just sent the image resId (seems to be ic_launcher, here) ?

Comment: please post the code where you download and set the Image to ImageView.

Comment: how to convert imageview into drawable

Comment: how to send it?(do u mean through intent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to convert the Bitmap to a byte array. Bitmap is parcelable so you can just use [`putParcelable(String, Parcelable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelable%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29) to add it to the Bundle.

**Edit:**

For example:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelable("Bitmap", bmp);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the second activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("Bitmap");
```

Comment: can u elabborate on this. Bundle extras=new Bundle();
   extras.putParcelable("Bitmap", bitmap);  is it write?

Comment: how much data can we send through intent. Is the large size image can create problem for me?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you pass image ID and set Id in Next Activity Imageview
E.g.

```
GEt ID  ((ImageView) v).getId();
SET ID  imageView.setImageResource(imgId);
```

Comment: I have set that image to imageview. Do u mean I should send imageview id to next activity through intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your ImageView To Bitmap.Try this

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView .getMeasuredWidth(),imageView .getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
ImageView .draw(canvas);
```